# Scheduling algorithm for a tournament with large number of participants?

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Say, we have 100+ participants and 3 winning places. I need to schedule as least matches as possible to find 3 winners. The rest of places doesn't matter at all.
Round-robin algorithm looks unnecessary expensive.

Here is my solution:

```
const match = (a, b) => {
  if (!a || !b) {
    return {winner: a || b}
  }
  // simulate match
  const winner = Math.random() > 0.5 ? a : b
  console.log(`Match between ${a} and ${b}: ${winner} wins`)
  return {winner, looser: winner === a ? b : a}
}
let participants = {
  // [id]: {win: Number, loose: Number}
}
let participantsNumber = 100
let n = 0

// create random participants
while(n < participantsNumber) {
  n++
  participants[String(n)] = {win: 0, loose: 0}
}

let round = 0
while(participantsNumber > 3) {
  let odd = true
  let matches = []
  _.map(participants, (winLooseStats, id) => {
    if (odd) {
      odd = false
      matches.push({player_1: id})
    } else {
      odd = true
      let opponentFound = false
      matches.map(match => {
        if (!match.player_2 && !opponentFound) {
          opponentFound = true
          match.player_2 = id
        }
      })
    }
  })
  console.log('matches', matches)
  // run matches
  matches.forEach(({player_1, player_2}) => {
    const {winner, looser} = match(player_1, player_2)
    participants[winner].win++
    if (looser) {
      participants[looser].loose++
    }
  })

  // remove those, who has lost 3 times
  _.map(participants, ({win, loose}, id) => {
    if (loose > 2) {
      console.log(`Player ${id} has lose 3 times`)
      delete participants[id]
      participantsNumber--
    }
  })
  round++
  console.log(`Round ${round} complete. ${participantsNumber} players left`)
}

console.log(`3 champions: ${_.map(participants, (wl, id) => id).join(', ')}`)
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rpqscnnv/)

~12 rounds per 100 participants. Is it possible to decrease number of rounds?

Comment: Well, 1 match with all 100+ participants fighting to the death until only 3 are left alive would satisfy your requirements.  For anything like an answer you'll have to provide a lot more detail.

Comment: This would be unfair, because some "players" may loose only once and they are would be already out of queue

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark i've added possible solution to description. It may clarify all the details

Comment: "the least matches as possible" somehow implies that players losing their first match are out. I assume that the outcome of a match is not a score but just win or lose.

Comment: @Henry, no need in score. However, this is not true: "losing their first match are out". In the script above they suppose to loose 3 matches. Then they are out. 3 matches, because i need to find 3 best players among 100+ players

Comment: But this does not lead to the minimal number of matches. You need to define any additional constraints you want to have fulfilled.

Comment: It's possible to use 5 rounds: divide the participants into three equal groups and run a single elimination in each. This gives 3 winners. I expect this solution is no good, but the question is woefully underspecified.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague, but I think your rules are as follows:

- Any pair of players plays no more than one match. If A beats B we assume A will always beat B.
- We assume a transitive property: if A beats B and B beats C the we can assume A beats C and we don't have to schedule a match to find that out.

Assuming that's correct and you have `n` players then you can solve this optimally using a standard [single elimination tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-elimination_tournament) to find the winner and 2nd place. To find 3rd place you have to add one more match between the two people who didn't make it to the final match.

Comment: [the example from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-elimination_tournament) seems not fair: if "Flavia Pennetta" has lost first match, it gets out of further matches. However, it doesn't mean that "Flavia Pennetta" can not beat, say, "Dominika Cibulková".

Comment: but, if "Flavia Pennetta" would be bitten three times, then it's clearly impossible to get one of first 3 places, right?